# My Mage_Shell script doesn't work: Mage::getModel() can't find class

Tags: magento-1.8, mage-shell

So, I just ran into this and scratched my head quite a few times and since the Magento bug tracker is dead, let's do it here.

Symptom:

```
Class 'MyNameSpace_MyModule_Helper_Data' not found in /var/www/example.com/app/Mage.php on line 547
```

This happens when a script is run, based on `shell/abstract.php`. The site works fine, so I know that the helper/model/block is working. What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short version:
You have `php_value include_path "some_path"` in `/var/www/example.com/.htaccess`.

Long version:

Let's take a look at `shell/abstract.php`:

```
    82      public function __construct()
    83      {
    84          if ($this->_includeMage) {
    85              require_once $this->_getRootPath() . 'app' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Mage.php';
    86              Mage::app($this->_appCode, $this->_appType);
    87          }
    88          $this->_factory = new Mage_Core_Model_Factory();
    89  
    90          $this->_applyPhpVariables();
```

At line 85 we include `app/Mage.php`. Among other things, just including this file sets up php's `include_path` to match Magento's architecture and configures the autoloader (`lib/Varien/Autoload.php`).

At line 90 the function _applyPhpVariables() is called. This is a mini-htaccess parser, that isn't well thought through, for two reasons:

1. It doesn't account for `.user.ini` that can do the same for [CGI based SAPIs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php),
2. It doesn't protect against foot shooting

Number 1, I won't address here, but it's not too hard to do this, since we have [parse_ini_file](http://php.net/parse_ini_file). Number 2 is the root cause of the problem you're seeing:

```
   114      protected function _applyPhpVariables()
   115      {
   116          $htaccess = $this->_getRootPath() . '.htaccess';
   117          if (file_exists($htaccess)) {
   118              // parse htaccess file
   119              $data = file_get_contents($htaccess);
   120              $matches = array();
   121              preg_match_all('#^\s+?php_value\s+([a-z_]+)\s+(.+)$#siUm', $data, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
   122              if ($matches) {
   123                  foreach ($matches as $match) {
   124                      @ini_set($match[1], str_replace("\r", '', $match[2]));
   125                  }
   126              }
```

This looks for any line in `magento_root/.htaccess` that defines `php_value` directives in a way that mod_php understands.

The problem is that `app/Mage.php` just went through all the trouble of setting up the include path, yet if we have `php_value include_path "/some/cool/app"` in our `.htaccess`, we will undo all that work in line 124.

So, if our shell script fetches a helper class, like:

```
$helper = Mage::getHelper('mynamespace_mymodule');
```

Varien/Autoload won't be able to find it.

The real fix is to teach `_applyPhpVariables` to never mangle include_path:

```
--- a/shell/abstract.php
+++ b/shell/abstract.php
@@ -121,6 +121,10 @@ abstract class Mage_Shell_Abstract
             preg_match_all('#^\s+?php_value\s+([a-z_]+)\s+(.+)$#siUm', $data, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
             if ($matches) {
                 foreach ($matches as $match) {
+                    // Never ever set include_path. app/Mage.php already did 
+                    // this and took the .htaccess value into account.
+                    if( $match[1] == 'include_path' )
+                        continue;
                     @ini_set($match[1], str_replace("\r", '', $match[2]));
                 }
             }
```

Hope this saves someone some time / hair-pulling.